# ITextSharp in Plugins

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, itext

I need to use ITextSharp (PDF tool) into one of my plugins.
I added references and I can use the ITextSharp functions, but when I trigger my plugin, I got this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'itextsharp, Version=5.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any idea to resolve it ?

Comment: How do you deploy your plugin?

Comment: I would recommend a custom wcf rest webservice, that will make use of `ITextSharp` and called from plugin. No need to worry about external dlls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CRM system couldn't find the ITextSharp dll in the places it used to search (GAC or global assembly cache), so you need to make several additional steps to force let it know where your dll is placed.
Look at this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309620.aspx
and also this blog: http://dorothyjarry.com/2012/08/17/crm-2011-plugin-causing-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-xrm-client-error/